# Python Pandas: if the data is NaN, then change to be 0, else change to be 1 in data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I have a DataFrame:df as following:

```
 row  id  name    age   url           
  1   e1   tom    NaN   http1   
  2   e2   john   25    NaN
  3   e3   lucy   NaN  http3 
  4   e4   tick   29    NaN
```

I want to change the NaN to be 0, else to be 1 in the columns: age, url.
My code is following, but it is wrong.

```
  import Pandas as pd

  df[['age', 'url']].applymap(lambda x: 0 if x=='NaN' else x)
```

I want to get the following result:

```
  row  id  name    age   url           
  1   e1   tom     0     1
  2   e2   john    1     0
  3   e3   lucy    0     1 
  4   e4   tick    1     0
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and condition by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html):

```
df[['age', 'url']] = df[['age', 'url']].where(df[['age', 'url']].isnull(), 1)
                                       .fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)

   row  id  name  age  url
0    1  e1   tom    0    1
1    2  e2  john    1    0
2    3  e3  lucy    0    1
3    4  e4  tick    1    0
```

Or [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html):

```
df[['age', 'url']] = np.where(df[['age', 'url']].isnull(), 0, 1)
print (df)
   row  id  name  age  url
0    1  e1   tom    0    1
1    2  e2  john    1    0
2    3  e3  lucy    0    1
3    4  e4  tick    1    0
```

Fastest solution with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) and [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df[['age', 'url']] = df[['age', 'url']].notnull().astype(int)
print (df)
   row  id  name  age  url
0    1  e1   tom    0    1
1    2  e2  john    1    0
2    3  e3  lucy    0    1
3    4  e4  tick    1    0
```

EDIT:

I try modify your solution:

```
df[['age', 'url']] = df[['age', 'url']].applymap(lambda x: 0 if pd.isnull(x) else 1)
print (df)
   row  id  name  age  url
0    1  e1   tom    0    1
1    2  e2  john    1    0
2    3  e3  lucy    0    1
3    4  e4  tick    1    0
```

**Timings**:

`len(df)=4k`:

```
In [127]: %timeit df[['age', 'url']] = df[['age', 'url']].applymap(lambda x: 0 if pd.isnull(x) else 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.2 ms per loop

In [128]: %timeit df[['age', 'url']] = np.where(df[['age', 'url']].isnull(), 0, 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop

In [129]: %timeit df[['age', 'url']] = np.where(pd.notnull(df[['age', 'url']]), 1, 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop

In [131]: %timeit df.loc[:, ['age', 'url']] = df[['age', 'url']].notnull() * 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop

In [136]: %timeit df[['age', 'url']] = df[['age', 'url']].notnull().astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop
```

Comment: thanks for your kind answers. I will accept it based on votes tomorrow.

Comment: you are great help me. Actually, the data frame is a large data frame, speed is important to me!

Comment: So then `piRSquared` solution is fastest.

Comment: I found faster solution as `piRSquared`, please see last edit.

Comment: you are the most passion and kindest, sometimes not just based on the best answer.  Now, I accept you! best wishes to you!

Comment: Thank you. Glad can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118396/discussion-between-tktktk0711-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 5):

Use `np.where` with `pd.notnull` to replace the missing and valid elements with `0` and `1` respectively:

```
In [90]:
df[['age', 'url']] = np.where(pd.notnull(df[['age', 'url']]), 1, 0)
df

Out[90]:
   row  id  name  age  url
0    1  e1   tom    0    1
1    2  e2  john    1    0
2    3  e3  lucy    0    1
3    4  e4  tick    1    0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.loc[:, ['age', 'url']] = df[['age', 'url']].notnull() * 1
df
```

[image]